# Difference between gdb, valgrind, strace, ltrace and apport

Tags: debugging, gdb, valgrind, strace, ltrace

I'm looking for the difference between the following debugging tools.

What are those?

**E:** On the off chance that somebody stumbles in here and was wondering about the same thing the "differences" are (shortened from the man pages):

- **`GDB`**

  Allows you to see what's going on "inside" a program while it runs/crashed.
- **`Valgrind`**

  A flexible series of tools for debugging and profiling.
- **`Strace`**

  Records/intercepts system calls which are called/received by a process.
- **`Ltrace`**

  Records/intercepts signals/dynamic library/system calls which are called/received by a process.
- **`Apport`**

  Intercepts crashes/unhandled exceptions, collects OS information, presents a helpful UI, and is able to file non-crash bugs.

Comment: Try reading their man pages. Your question is not unlike "what's different between apples and oranges".

Comment: +1 for posting a succinct followup answer. i only knew about gdb. times are a changing ;)

Comment: (Still, as useful as this may be, a question like this is obviously off-topic for Stack Overflow.)

Comment: @hyde I don't find it obvious.